# Can a question be moved from Travel.SE to Aviation.SE

Tags: support, migration

When I asked my [question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/50694/19990) "Is there an IATA airport code that is unassigned and that can be used for 'any airport'?" in Travel.SE I didn't realise there was an Aviation.SE that would probably be a better place to ask it, as a user pointed out. Is it possible to move it, or do I have to re-post it?

Comment: Flag it for moderator attention, then use the "Other" reason to explain the migration request.

Comment: Yep, I've already flagged it for a mod to move it,  hopefully they'll do so shortly.

Comment: (please don't repost it, people get upset about that. You'll post it on aviation, then a mod will move this one from here to aviation, and then there's a duplicate and all hell breaks loose, dogs and cats living together, madness! ;))

Comment: The [area51 stats for the Aviation site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42572/aviation) look pretty good to me, so I wouldn't think it at too much risk!

Comment: @Gagravarr wow, yeah, they must get promoted soon, surely

Answer (score 3):

Q did get migrated and Aviation.SE is now fully fledged.

May be time for [status-completed].